# Using & with fpdf and mysql causes problems

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

It seems i have stumbled onto a unforeseen problem with fpdf when using & in a sentence.

My php file gets information from a mysql database. And unfortunately I noticed if the field contains a `&` symbol the command fails. Basically what happens is if the sentence says `Me, my partner & our friends` the fpdf command only posts `Me, my partner` and ignores the rest...

I do not use the $_GET to pass the values, but rather $_POST, so i do not believe the & sign should conflict should it?

I have been spending quite some time searching for answers, but I do not see any mention of it...

Any assistance would be great.

Comment: odd, but test `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Hi @Dagon i added it like this `$pdf->Cell(0,5,htmlspecialchars($company_name),"B",1,"C");` but it still had the same result, sentence cut off at the `&` sign.

Comment: Did you already tried [`utf8_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) instead of htmlspecialchars?

Comment: I have found the issue, it seemed that the Delphi plugin which posts the value had a bug, it never posted anything after the &. Since the supplier fixed the issue it seems to work.